# How to call awk from bash with last field as variable

Tags: bash, csv, awk, field

Suppose I have a CSV input file called input.csv:

```
1,2,3,valueIWantToPrint
3,5,2,valueIWantToPrint
```

I currently need to print the last element of each row of that input with awk, which is easily accomplished with the field separator and NF variables:

```
awk -F"," '{print $NF}' input.csv
```

But now let's say that I want to make the field that I want to print a variable, because later perhaps the input format will change and it will be a different field.

Input file:

```
1,2,valueIWantToPrint,3
3,5,valueIWantToPrint,2
```

Script:

```
FIELD_TO_PRINT=3
awk -F"," -v fieldToPrint=FIELD_TO_PRINT '{print $fieldToPrint}' input.csv
```

Ok, that was easy.  But now to make it as flexible as possible, I would like have the ability to set FIELD_TO_PRINT to the equivalent of NF so that I can print the last value regardless of the number of fields.  What I'm after is something like this:

Input:

```
1,2,3,7,2,5,23,1,3,6,valueIWantToPrint
3,5,2,6,3,valueIWantToPrint
```

This script doesn't work, but illustrates what I am trying to accomplish:

```
FIELD_TO_PRINT=NF
awk -F"," -v fieldToPrint=FIELD_TO_PRINT '{print $fieldToPrint}' input.csv
```

Is there a convenient way to set a variable to mean "the last field in record?"  This example is pretty trivial, but ultimately the FIELD_TO_PRINT variable will be put in a separate configuration file, and the awk script will be much larger and more complex.  So having a good way to accomplish this will be very useful.

Comment: Are all rows expected to have same number of columns? The other file you are taking about can run a command? i.e. Can `FIELD_TO_PRINT` be an output of a command?

Comment: I'm lost - `awk -F, '{print $NF}' file` does exactly that -- prints *"the last field in record"*, so it will output `valueIWantToPrint` in your last example. Do you want something different?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: OP says the column number is dynamic I suppose, so if the pass `NF` as the variable value, it is not working

Comment: That's why I'm scratching my head, `NF` is the per-row (*record*) number of fields -- it's not a fixed value for the entire file. It will handle both lines in the last example properly.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: My point is `$ awk -F"," -v fieldToPrint="NF" '{print $fieldToPrint}' file` won't work as expected, but `$ awk -F"," '{print $NF}' file` will

Comment: Yes, I got you there, `NF` at the beginning of the bash script has no meaning and will simply be undefined.

Comment: Sorry for any head-scratching caused by the write-up.  The requirements for this script are currently dynamic, so rather than writing the awk script in such a way that it uses NF to find the last field in the record, I would rather pass in a variable to govern whether awk prints the last field or the nth field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this round-about way:

Negative `n` means `NF`:

```
n=-1
awk -F, -v n="$n" '{print (n<0 ? $NF : $n)}' f.csv
```

```
valueIWantToPrint
valueIWantToPrint
```

and when `n > 0` print numbered field:

```
n=3
awk -F, -v n="$n" '{print (n<0 ? $NF : $n)}' f.csv
```

```
3
2
```

Comment: Oh, so he wantsa *ternary* for either the specified field or the last. Now that makes more sense.

Comment: This _cannot_ be a round-about way, this _is_ the way! `++`

Comment: Awesome!  This is exactly what I was after

Answer (score 3):

you can use this trick

```
$ awk -F, -v n=-1 '{print (n<0)?$(NF+n+1):$n}' file

valueIWantToPrint
valueIWantToPrint
```

assume negative indices start counting from NF backwards, so -2 will mean the penultimate field etc.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest.